# Отображать процесс выполнения действия

Tags: yii2

Хочу выполнить следующее.... Загружаю файл, (импорт из excel). Контроллер отрабатывает его и пользователю хочу показывать сколько процентов завершено. Как мне возвращать ответ в процентах, что бы не прерывалась задача?